# PyQt5 or Pyqt4, should I do the upgrade?

Tags: pyqt4, pyqt5

I kind of have some trouble understanding Python in general as I am programming in that language for 8 months now. I am really good in programming but Python is really a big problem for me. If you need to upgrade from Pyqt4 to Pyqt5 you need to download so many packages and then they don't even work. But that is not my question. My question is the following:

I have found out that to use Pyqt5 you definitely going to buy a license. If that is the case does it really make sense to upgrade from Pyqt4? What kind of advantages would I get if do upgrade? How much would licensing cost?
How long would the debugging process be if I do upgrade the GUI?

I had some trouble with the qtdesigner it has some bugs in it and I thought I could fix those and make my GUI **more fancy** by upgrading to the latest version. I just didn't realise that I will face that much problems. Which is why I am raising this question.

A detailed answer is very appreciated. Just so I can answer my colleagues.

Comment: PyQt5 is available under GPL and commercial licenses, so what is the problem with just using the GPL version?

Comment: I will need a designer with my version. Does this version comes with an designer? Where can I find that version anyway?

Comment: You mean the Qt Designer? That is part of Qt, not PyQt.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5 is available under GPL and commercial licenses.

`PyQt5 can be installed alongside PyQt4 using the same Python interpreter without any problems so long as they are built with the same version of SIP.`

You can see Differences Between PyQt4 and PyQt5 at:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html

https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: @Mohammadrezahedayatnia I think this link will help youhttps://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html